# How to read .dat file and display corresponding image in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a `.dat` file in which every column corresponds to one image. I want to display a given image, such as the 5th one etc. How do I read a `.dat` file in Python and display the image associated with a given column?

Comment: Huh? Please show the contents of the `.dat` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this part of the code:

```
Image_array = np.loadtxt('Image_name .dat')

plt.imshow(Image_array,aspect="auto")
plt.show()
```